# VBA macro to sum by group

Tags: excel, vba

suppose I have a table looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eolJb.png)

[image]

I am trying to count the total number by (from to index), the desired output will look like this as in last column:
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDhyy.png)

[image]

please advise how to achieve this in VBA macro, thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Hi, this site is to help those who hav done research and shown they have attempted to write code. Once you do some research, write your code and if it dosn't work, please then post back and we can review.

Comment: Can you show what your expected output would be?

Comment: Are you open to a pivot table solution? Or excel function solution? This does not have to be VBA

Comment: It looks like this is also a function of your `Ship` `No Ship` results. Can you confirm more of the logic here? What is your Index column? How is this populated?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim Lastrow As Long, i As Long, CurrentIndex As Long, NextIndex As Long, WholeIndex As Long
    Dim CurrentKey As String, NextKey As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To Lastrow

            CurrentKey = .Range("B" & i).Value & "_" & .Range("C" & i).Value & "_" & .Range("D" & i).Value & "_" & .Range("E" & i).Value
            CurrentIndex = .Range("D" & i).Value
            NextKey = .Range("B" & i + 1).Value & "_" & .Range("C" & i + 1).Value & "_" & .Range("D" & i + 1).Value & "_" & .Range("E" & i + 1).Value
            NextIndex = .Range("D" & i + 1).Value

            If CurrentKey = NextKey Then
                    If WholeIndex = 0 Then
                        WholeIndex = CurrentIndex + NextIndex
                    Else
                        WholeIndex = WholeIndex + NextIndex
                    End If
            Else
                If WholeIndex > 1 Then
                    .Range("F" & i).Value = WholeIndex

                End If

                WholeIndex = 0

            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```